# Динамически создать маршруты ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Добрый день.

Имеется коллекция routes длины N. i-тый элемент содержит свойства, скажем, url и name. Требуется сконфигурировать на главной странице маршруты к url'ам, указанным в данном массиве.

В HTML, как я понимаю, выходит код вроде такого:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="route in routes"><a ui-sref="{{route.url}}">{{route.name}}<a></li>
</ul>
```

i-тый ui-sref указывает на i-тый url.

Не могу сообразить, как в таком случае прописать в конфиге $stateProvider. Обычный код вроде такого

```
$stateProvider
        .state('page0', {
            url: 'page0',
            templateUrl: 'page0.htm',
        })
```

как я понимаю, здесь не подходит, т.к. на этапе конфигурирования ещё нет коллекции routes. Как это сделать в runtime динамически? Идеально было бы в виде функции, которая проходит по коллекции routes, и добавляет в $stateProvider маршруты

Comment: У вас коллекция `routes` часто меняется? Если не часто, то я не вижу смысла заполнять `$stateProvider` динамически.

Comment: ну а вы представьте, что их всего, ну скажем, 33. Например, ссылки на ресурсы, отсортированные по буквам алфавита. Всего 33 ссылки по количеству букв.

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, я не вижу смысла создавать роутинги динамически.

Но, если очень нужно, то можно сделать так.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6dop8sdg/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ["ui.router"])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    //Статический роутинг
    $stateProvider
      .state('a', {
        url: '/a',
        template: '<h2>A template</h2>'
      });
    //Добавляем данные по роутингу, загруженные через AJAX.
    angular.forEach(ROUTES, function(item) {
      $stateProvider
        .state(item.name, {
          url: '/' + item.url,
          template: '<h2>' + item.name + ' template</h2>'
        })
    })
  });
var ROUTES;
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  //После загрузки страницы, запрашиваем наши данные по роутингу
  $.ajax("/getRoutes", {
    complete: function(data) {
      //допустим, что data- массив вида [{name:"c",url:"c"}]
      ROUTES = [{
        name: "c",
        url: "c"
      }];
      //Запускаем приложение angular вручную, после загрузки всех роутингов.
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['ExampleApp']);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a ui-sref="a">Static</a>
  <a ui-sref="c">Dynamic</a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Без использования `jQuery`.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/cwczdu9r/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ["ui.router"])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    //Статический роутинг
    $stateProvider
      .state('a', {
        url: '/a',
        template: '<h2>A template</h2>'
      });
    //Добавляем данные по роутингу, загруженные через AJAX.
    angular.forEach(angular.module('ExampleApp').ROUTES, function(item) {
      $stateProvider
        .state(item.name, {
          url: '/' + item.url,
          template: '<h2>' + item.name + ' template</h2>'
        })
    })
  });
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  //После загрузки страницы, запрашиваем наши данные по роутингу
  var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ui.router']);
  var $http = $injector.get("$http");
  $http.get("https://google.com").error(function(data) {
    //допустим, что data- массив вида [{name:"c",url:"c"}]
    var data = [{
      name: "c",
      url: "c"
    }];
    var app = angular.module('ExampleApp');
    //Сохраняем в модуль ExampleApp наши роутинги, что бы не засорять глобальное пространство
    app.ROUTES = data;
    //Запускаем приложение angular вручную, после загрузки всех роутингов.
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['ExampleApp']);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-cloak>
  <a ui-sref="a">Static</a>
  <a ui-sref="c">Dynamic</a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: нерабочий пример в сниппете: _Failed to instantiate module ExampleApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider_

Comment: в таком виде статический роутинг не нужен, ведь на момент разворачивания приложения все роуты уже доступны

Comment: ну и в идеале - убрать jQuery

Comment: Извините, не очень понял про статический роутинг. Если вы про роутинг, который ссылается на `a template`, то он оставлен для сравнения с динамиеским, что бы было видно, что разницы между динамическим и статическим нет.

Comment: Если убрать `jquery`, то придется `ajax` вызов писать через `XHR`. Мне кажется, использование `$.ajax` более интуитивно понятно для большинства разработчиков.

Comment: Конечно, желательно еще все завернуть в `IIFE`, разделить `complete` на `success` и `error` в вызове `$.ajax`. Но мне кажется, что в констексте данного вопроса это лишнее)

Comment: Нет, можно же получить сервис $http и использовать его

Comment: Мне кажется, использования сервиса `$http` вне ангуляра не настолько интуитивно понятное. Но если вы против `jQuery`, то можно и без него.

Comment: Это намного лучше, чем тянуть jQuery только ради одного запроса

Comment: Согласен, лучше `jQuery` ради одного запроса не тянуть. Если `jQuery`еще нет в проекте, конечно)